# How to refresh entire database from a linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, refresh

I have a linked server hosted externally (SQL Server) and would like to refresh the data everyday. What I have tried is truncate the data in the destination table and insert the data from the source database.

I have about 100 tables to refresh from external source. Is there a better way to refresh the entire database without having to refresh each table?

Source Database : MySQL
Destination Database: SQL Server

```
use [Audits] 
GO 
TRUNCATE TABLE [Products_data].[r_rooms] 
GO 
INSERT INTO [Products_data].[r_rooms] 
Select * from [ProdcutRemote]...[Products_data.r_rooms]
```

Comment: Why not merge the data? Only copy over what has changed?

Comment: Since you're only doing it once a day, and you're doing every table ("the entire database"), the simplest solution by far would be to simply backup the database and restore it on the other server, assuming the instance versions allow for it.

Comment: If you want refresh the entire database then clearly you have to update each table - SQL Server has numerous options for this including change tracking, log shipping and database mirroring, depending on your use-case (which you don't elaborate on).

Comment: @Dalek  Sorry to mention in my question, the source database is MySQL where as my destination  database is in SQL server. Would above suggestion still work?